# How could I avoid instantiating using the new keyword?

Tags: c#, oop

I'm just a student trying to get better. 
Right now I am developing an application which reads from Excel. For that I have a class, DataReader.

```
public class DataReader : IDataReader
{
    Workbook workbook;
    public DataReader()
    {
        workbook = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook);
    }


    public Worksheet GetWorksheetByName(string name)
    {
        Worksheet sheet = (Worksheet)Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(workbook.Worksheets[name]);
        return sheet;
    }


}
```

and this class I am calling from multiple places. Here's an example of how I'm I'm instantiating it in one class

```
    public List<ConfigModel> Instances { get; set; }
    public IDataReader dr;
    public Worksheet sheet;
    public PopulateConfigModel()
    {
        Instances = new List<ConfigModel>();
        dr = new DataReader();
        sheet = dr.GetWorksheetByName("Your_Data_Sheet");
    }
```

and here is another example

```
public class RangeCreator : IRangeCreator
{
    IDataReader dr;
    Worksheet sheet;
    public Xcl.Range GetDestinationRange()
    {
        dr = new DataReader();
        DataHandler dh = new DataHandler();
        sheet = dr.GetWorksheetByName("Your_CSV_File");
        string range = "A" + ((dh.GetLastRow(sheet) + 1) + ":A" + (dh.GetLastRow(sheet) + 3));
        Xcl.Range rng = sheet.Range[range];
        return rng;
    }
```

Note that I also calls new DataHandler in that method.

I don't think this is good practice but I don't have a better solution so what's the work around for instantiating this class multiple places? I guess I could go with DI but then I'd have to DI both the DataReader and DataHandler in multiple places and I'm not sure that's a better solution.

I don't know,

UPDATE:

```
public void BeginProcess()
    {
        dh = new DataHandler1();
        //Returns a List<List<int>> with all used boxsizes {{ 5,1 }, { 15, 3 }} & startCell for each of those boxes eg {{ "B6" }, { "B27" }}
        ListHandler lh = dh.GetListHandlerData();
        //Holds a list of instances
        IPopulateConfigModel pc = new PopulateConfigModel();
        //For hver boks vi har i dokumentet
        for (int i = 0; i < lh.cellAddresses.Count; i++)
        {
            //Adds list of instances to list of models 
            models.Add(pc.PopulateInstances(lh.boxSizes[i], lh.cellAddresses[i]));
        }

        ConfigModelHandler cm = new ConfigModelHandler(models);

        cm.StartModelProcessing(dh);
    }
```

Now I am injecting the DataHandler as a parameter in StartModelProcessing

```
public void StartModelProcessing(IDataHandler1 dh)
    {
        IFileSaver fileSaver = new FileSaver();
        Worksheet sheet = dr.GetWorksheetByName("Your_CSV_File");
        //Each model - each with their own sheet
        for (int i = 0; i < models.Count; i++)
        {
            //Contains all instances of an object
            string[][] instances = new string[models[i].Count][];

            string filePath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\" + models[i][0].TemplateName + ".csv";
            //Clears our sheet so we're ready for a new set of instances 
            dh.ClearWorksheet(sheet);
            //Each instance - sharing their worksheet
            for (int j = 0; j < models[i].Count; j++)
            {
                Xcl.Range rngPopulated = GetPopulatedSourceRange(models[i][j]);

                string[] rows = new string[3];

                //Get our data from our populated range to our string array. It's in the form of:
                /*
                 * one string array = one instance
                 * rows[0] = TEMPLATE
                 * rows[1] = Properties
                 * rows[2] = Variables
                 */
                for (int ti = 0; ti < rngPopulated.Rows.Count; ti++)
                {
                    for (int tu = 1; tu < rngPopulated.Rows[ti + 1].Cells.Count; tu++)
                    {
                        rows[ti] += rngPopulated.Rows[ti + 1].Cells[tu].Value2 + ",";
                    }
                }
                instances[j] = rows;
                Xcl.Range testRange = rangeGetter.GetDestinationRange(dh);
                //We aint using this sheet - it's only if the user will change and save it manually but only last instance of last document is showing
                di.PopulateCsvFile(rows, testRange);

            }

            fileSaver.SaveFile(instances, filePath);
        }
    }
```

and as you can see, injecting it as a parameter again in the rangeGetter.GetDestRange method.

and here's the method

```
public Xcl.Range GetDestinationRange(IDataHandler1 dh)
    {
        dr = new DataReader1();
        sheet = dr.GetWorksheetByName("Your_CSV_File");
        string range = "A" + ((dh.GetLastRow(sheet) + 1) + ":A" + (dh.GetLastRow(sheet) + 3));
        Xcl.Range rng = sheet.Range[range];
        return rng;
    }
```

Comment: You can use Singleton pattern

Comment: Looks like you want `public static class DataReader`.

Comment: In your last example with `RangeCreator` I don't see the reason to inject both `DataReader` and `DataHandler`. You use `DataReader` only to get a sheet and then you pass it to `DataHandler`. So I would say you probably should join both classes into one `IExcelDataParser`.

Comment: You need instance to access instance members. You didn't show `DataHandler`, maybe its methods can be made static?

Comment: i dont see any issues with the way you have it, could you explain more as to why you "don't think this is good practice" what specifically are you referring to, and why? why should it be a "singleton"* or what ever you think it should be... what coding practice (bad practice) are you trying to solve., there isn't enough code here for me to be able to say that anyone thing should be moved..., example you move "dr" out of method but dont show that your consuming it again, so i would say you could initialize that in the constructor rather than the method, thats one thing which is odd.

Comment: Well I wanna change up my code because I've always gotten told instantiating using the new keyword is bad but also like when we're working with Repositories and such then I'm normally injecting them through their constructors and calling it with an IoC but I don't think that's a good solution either if I'd have to both call up DataReader and DataHandler multiple times. Basically I'm a noob asking the pros if there's a better solution than mine from the info I've given

Comment: In your case I would constructor inject or parameter inject the DataHandler. Let the caller provide the instance.

Comment: You might be interested in [`Lazy<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @CRice I've tried to apply and updated the OP. Would you mind giving your thoughts if that's the solution you thought about?

Comment: Dependency Injection

Comment: please show the code so that we can see where instances like dr are initialize .

Comment: @IDR At some point you need to new it up. But this can be done once at the top level and then injected to all the classes or methods requiring it. Otherwise it needs to be static and you can call directly to it, but you need to consider if you will ever need to substitute it out for testing. Static calls wont allow this but injection will.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to make DataReader class as singleton pattern like:

```
class DataReader
{       
     private static DataReader instance = null;
     private DataReader()
     {
       //workbook goes here...
     }

     public static DataReader Instance
     {
         get
         {
             if (instance == null)                   
                  instance = new DataReader();               
               return instance;
          }
      }     
}
```

And then you can call the method like:

```
...
sheet = DataReader.Instance.GetWorksheetByName("Your_CSV_File");
```

Here you not need to use the `new` keyword every time

Answer (score 0):

please understand

this is very "sudo code" and just here to illiterate that what is more important than trying to avoid "new" is how code is consumed by other code.

your code is hard to comment on as the whole picture cannot be seen... (what belongs to what)

If you don't understand what I'm trying to show below then i will delete, but if you do then great! I have ommited a lot of code to make it easier to understand... well hopefully

```
class Main 
{

    DataReader1 _dr;
    DataHandler _dh;
    public Main()
    {
        _dr = new DataReader1();
        _dh = new DataHandler();
        BeginProcess();
    }

    public void BeginProcess()
    {
        //...code ommitted
        ConfigModelHandler cm = new ConfigModelHandler(models);
        cm.StartModelProcessing();
    }

    public void StartModelProcessing(IDataHandler1 dh)
    {   
        Worksheet sheet = dr.GetWorksheetByName("Your_CSV_File");
        //Each model - each with their own sheet
        for (int i = 0; i < models.Count; i++)
        {
                for (int j = 0; j < models[i].Count; j++)
            {
                Worksheet sheetInner = dr.GetWorksheetByName("Your_CSV_File");
                //do stuff with sheet
                var range = GetDestinationRange(sheetInner);
            }

            fileSaver.SaveFile(instances, filePath);
        }
    }

    public Xcl.Range GetDestinationRange(Worksheet sheet)
    {
        var lastRow = dh.GetLastRow(sheet);
        string range = "A" + ((lastRow  + 1) + ":A" + (lastRow + 3));
        Xcl.Range rng = sheet.Range[range];
        return rng;
    }
}
```